# Find pattern in string using regex with python 3

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, python-3.x

I have string like below

> string = "your invoice number  IVR/20170531/XVII/V/12652967 and IVR/20170531/XVII/V/13652967"

I want to get invoice number IVR/20170531/XVII/V/12652967 and IVR/20170531/XVII/V/13652967  into list using regex with this pattern

```
       result = re.findall(r'INV[/]\d{8}[/](M{1,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|C?D|D?C{1,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|X?L|L?X{1,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|I?V|V?I{1,3}))[/](M{1,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|C?D|D?C{1,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|X?L|L?X{1,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|I?V|V?I{1,3}))[/]\d{7,9}',string)
```

but the result is

```
[('XVII',  '', '','',  '', '',  '',  '', 'X',  'VII', '',  '', '',  'V','','','',  '', '',  '', '',  '', '',  '', '',  'V')]
```

I tried this pattern in http://regexr.com/, the result is appropriately but in python not

Comment: Which part is the invoice number in the sample string you gave?

Comment: `IVR[^\s]+` right?

Comment: I think you need a few additional `|` in your pattern... https://regex101.com/r/OZNSem/1

Comment: IVR/[number]/[roman]/[roman]/[number]

Comment: @l'L'l have the same result with that

Comment: @depperm all the same

Comment: You could always filter the results and eliminate the empty tuples (eg. `for r in result: print(filter(None, r))`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your pattern, add normal brackets around whole regular expression, and afterwards access that text with first back-reference. You can read more about back-references [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

```
invoices = []
# Your pattern was slightly incorrect
pattern = re.compile(r'IVR[/]\d{8}[/](M{1,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})|(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|C?D|D?C{1,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|X?L|L?X{1,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|I?V|V?I{1,3}))[/](M{1,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})|(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})|(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|C?D|D?C{1,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|X?L|L?X{1,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|I?V|V?I{1,3}))[/]\d{7,9}') 

# For each invoice pattern you find in string, append it to list
for invoice in pattern.finditer(string):
    invoices.append(invoice.group(1))
```

**Note:**

You should also use `pattern.finditter()` because that way you can iterate trough all pattern findings in text you called `string`. From *re.finditer* documentation:

> re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0) 
>   Return an iterator yielding
>   MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE
>   pattern in string. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches
>   are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the
>   result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "your invoice number IVR/20170531/XVII/V/12652967 and IVR/20170531/XVII/V/13652967"
results = []
matches = re.finditer(regexpattern, string)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    results.append(match.group())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `?:` before all the groups so that you can use [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon)

Try with this regex:

```
IVR[/]\d{8}[/](?:M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})|(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))[/](?:M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})|(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))[/]\d{8}
```

Basically you need to add `?:` for each group.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one to retrieve number, roman, roman and number values:

`IVR\/(\d{8})\/(M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))\/(M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))\/(\d{7,9})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WbQaBO/2)

**Snippet**

```
import re

string = "your invoice number IVR/20170531/XVII/V/12652967 and IVR/20170531/XVII/V/13652967"

pattern = r"IVR\/(\d{8})\/(M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))\/(M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))\/(\d{7,9})"

for match in re.findall(pattern, string):
    print(match)
```

[Run online](https://repl.it/IvDP/1)